Sage can't solve large nonlinear equation system
I am trying to solve a nonlinear equation system with Sage Math. The system has 17 equations and 11 unknowns. Sage does not return anything, no error, nothing. Just hangs. I don't know what is the problem and searched trough web but couldn't solve the issue. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. (Not sure if it's okay to ask this on StackOverlow)
A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, c, lambd = var('A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 c lambd')

eq1 = 32*A2*lambd^4 - 48*A4*lambd^2 + A0^2 - 2*A0*c + B1^2 == 0
eq2 = -10*B1*lambd^4 + 56*B3*lambd^4 - 2*B1*lambd^2 + 4*B3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B1 - 2*B1*c == 0
eq3 = -32*A1*lambd^4 + 240*A3*lambd^4 - 4*A1*lambd^2 + 12*A3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A1 - 2*A1*c == 0
eq4 = -272*A2*lambd^4 + 960*A4*lambd^4 - 16*A2*lambd^2 + 24*A2*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A2 + A1^2 - 2*A2*c == 0
eq5 = 80*A1*lambd^4 - 1152*A3*lambd^4 + 4*A1*lambd^2 - 36*A3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A3 + 2*A1*A2 - 2*A3*c == 0
eq6 = 480*A2*lambd^4 - 3392*A4*lambd^4 + 12*A2*lambd^2 - 64*A4*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A4 + 2*A1*A3 + A2^2 - 2*A4*c == 0
eq7 = -48*A1*lambd^4 + 1632*A3*lambd^4 + 24*A3*lambd^2 + 2*A1*A4 + 2*A2*A3 == 0
eq8 = -240*A2*lambd^4 + 4160*A4*lambd^4 + 40*A4*lambd^2 + 2*A2*A4 + A3^2 == 0
eq9 = -720*A3*lambd^4 + 2*A3*A4 - 2*B3*B4 == 0
eq10 = -1680*A4*lambd^4 + A4^2 - B4^2 == 0
eq11 = -122*B2*lambd^4 + 360*B4*lambd^4 - 10*B2*lambd^2 + 12*B4*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B2 + 2*A1*B1 - 2*B2*c == 0
eq12 = 56*B1*lambd^4 - 634*B3*lambd^4 + 4*B1*lambd^2 - 26*B3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B3 + 2*A1*B2 + 2*A2*B1 - 2*B3*c == 0
eq13 = 360*B2*lambd^4 - 2122*B4*lambd^4 + 12*B2*lambd^2 - 50*B4*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B4 + 2*A1*B3 + 2*A2*B2 + 2*A3*B1 - 2*B4 == 0
eq14 = -48*B1*lambd^4 + 1296*B3*lambd^4 + 24*B3*lambd^2 + 2*A1*B4 + 2*A2*B3 + 2*A3*B2 + 2*A4*B1 == 0
eq15 = -240*B2*lambd^4 + 3440*B4*lambd^4 + 40*B4*lambd^2 + 2*A2*B4 + 2*A3*B3 + 2*A4*B2 == 0
eq16 = -720*B3*lambd^4 + 2*A3*B4 + 2*A4*B3 == 0
eq17 = -1680*B4*lambd^4 + 2*A4*B4 == 0

solutions = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11, eq12, eq13, eq14, eq15, eq16, eq17], A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, c, lambd)

By the way, MAPLE did this in just miliseconds.
Thanks in advance.

17 equations, 11 unknowns … I trust that you’ve checked your over-specified answer.

@lastchance, I took the equation system from an academic article and solved it in MAPLE and everything was okay. But I can't do this in Sage.

Well, one solution would be all variables=0.

I know the solutions. I solved it with MAPLE. But I need to solve it with Sage. That is my problem, it can't. @lastchance (One of the known solution is A0 = 33/169, A1 = 0, A2 = -210/169, A3 = 0, A4 = 105/169, B1 = 0, B2 = 0, B3 = 0, B4 = 0, c = -36/169, lambd = (1/2)*sqrt(13) )

Well, looks like only even powers of lambd appear, so you can replace lambd^2 with a new variable, let's say, lambd2, and likewise replace lambd^4 with lambd2^2. That reduces the maximum degree from 5 to 3, doesn't it? Looking for subproblems that are simpler, looks like you could solve for A4 and B4 in terms of lambd2, and then substitute those values into the other equations ... Looks like this is going to be very messy. My advice is to try to use the Maple solution if at all possible. Failing that, look at simpler problems of the same kind to get a feel for the possible solutions.

@RobertDodier, thank you. This seems to be worked. I got a couple solutions, Haven't checked them, but some solutions have something like r1, do you know what that means?

r1 means an arbitrary real variable: could take any value. Just as a matter of interest, exactly what "solutions" does Maple give?

Similar questions have been asked on Ask Sage, for instance: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/11070

@lastchance, here is some of them.

@Samuel Lelièvre, I saw that post but couldn't get it. My dimension was 3 and variety() was not working because dim is not 0.

Sage's symbolic ring (the structure you get when using var) is based on sympy and not particularly good at solving polynomial equations. I believe Maple uses an implementation of the F4 algorithm to solve these systems, which you may get access to in Sage by using polynomial rings instead:
sage: R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, c, lambd')
sage: A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, c, lambd = R.gens()
sage: 
sage: eq1 = 32*A2*lambd^4 - 48*A4*lambd^2 + A0^2 - 2*A0*c + B1^2
....: eq2 = -10*B1*lambd^4 + 56*B3*lambd^4 - 2*B1*lambd^2 + 4*B3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B1 - 2*B1*c
....: eq3 = -32*A1*lambd^4 + 240*A3*lambd^4 - 4*A1*lambd^2 + 12*A3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A1 - 2*A1*c
....: eq4 = -272*A2*lambd^4 + 960*A4*lambd^4 - 16*A2*lambd^2 + 24*A2*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A2 + A1^2 - 2*A2*c
....: eq5 = 80*A1*lambd^4 - 1152*A3*lambd^4 + 4*A1*lambd^2 - 36*A3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A3 + 2*A1*A2 - 2*A3*c
....: eq6 = 480*A2*lambd^4 - 3392*A4*lambd^4 + 12*A2*lambd^2 - 64*A4*lambd^2 + 2*A0*A4 + 2*A1*A3 + A2^2 - 2*A4*c
....: eq7 = -48*A1*lambd^4 + 1632*A3*lambd^4 + 24*A3*lambd^2 + 2*A1*A4 + 2*A2*A3
....: eq8 = -240*A2*lambd^4 + 4160*A4*lambd^4 + 40*A4*lambd^2 + 2*A2*A4 + A3^2
....: eq9 = -720*A3*lambd^4 + 2*A3*A4 - 2*B3*B4
....: eq10 = -1680*A4*lambd^4 + A4^2 - B4^2
....: eq11 = -122*B2*lambd^4 + 360*B4*lambd^4 - 10*B2*lambd^2 + 12*B4*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B2 + 2*A1*B1 - 2*B2*c
....: eq12 = 56*B1*lambd^4 - 634*B3*lambd^4 + 4*B1*lambd^2 - 26*B3*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B3 + 2*A1*B2 + 2*A2*B1 - 2*B3*c
....: eq13 = 360*B2*lambd^4 - 2122*B4*lambd^4 + 12*B2*lambd^2 - 50*B4*lambd^2 + 2*A0*B4 + 2*A1*B3 + 2*A2*B2 + 2*A3*B1 - 2*B4
....: eq14 = -48*B1*lambd^4 + 1296*B3*lambd^4 + 24*B3*lambd^2 + 2*A1*B4 + 2*A2*B3 + 2*A3*B2 + 2*A4*B1
....: eq15 = -240*B2*lambd^4 + 3440*B4*lambd^4 + 40*B4*lambd^2 + 2*A2*B4 + 2*A3*B3 + 2*A4*B2
....: eq16 = -720*B3*lambd^4 + 2*A3*B4 + 2*A4*B3
....: eq17 = -1680*B4*lambd^4 + 2*A4*B4
....: 
sage: I = R.ideal([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6, eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11, eq12, eq13, eq14, eq15, eq16, eq17])

A Gröbner basis is computed in a few seconds on my laptop:
sage: %time I.groebner_basis()
CPU times: user 34.1 s, sys: 53.6 ms, total: 34.2 s
Wall time: 34.1 s
Polynomial Sequence with 169 Polynomials in 11 Variables

The variety is 3-dimensional:
sage: I.dimension()
3

I'm not sure under what form you want the answer, but a Gröbner basis for the appropriate monomial order will give it to you.

I saw something like this but couldn't get it. I don't know any Rings (only some Group Theory). I will look more into it and leave a comment again. Thanks. (Btw, the answer I want was just like this, what maple gave.) I solved the system by using a var lambd2 and replacing the lambd^2 with this. Than it gave a solution after couple minutes and I just used sqrt(lambd2) in lambda.
